# How to decode nested / imported protobuf using protoc command line or python

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am debugging the api response which in protobuf format.

I know that I can using the protoc command to make the response readable:

```
protoc --decode api.Response response.proto < res.bin
```

It works on the simple files.
However, I find that some data is wrapped into the response protobuf like:

```
// response.proto

...
...

message Response {
  int64 status = 1;
  google.protobuf.Any detail = 2
  ...
}
```

```
// login.proto
...
...
...
// Import UserDatas protobufs...

message LoginResponse {
 string token = 1;
 UserDetail user = 2;
 UserLastLogin lastlogin = 3;
 ...
 ...
 ...
}
```

then I run the command

```
protoc --decode api.Response response.proto < res.bin
```

I got

```
status: 200
result {
  type_url: "........login",
  value: "(very long encoded text without formatting)"
}
```

I know that I can edit the proto file to change the `Any` to the `LoginResponse`,and decode it. However I have multiple API protobufs in this format, I cannot edit all the files each time I want to view.

I also ask the developer who using the response, but he told me he just checking the  `type_url` and using different function to parse the `value` data.  it looks not good (need to write many functions to handle it, generate the files for all proto and re-generate the library when the proto is updated).

I believe that there are better solutions.

Is there a simpler way to view the response **without** editing the proto file? (Hope that is able to do on `protoc` command or python)